# What exactly is the Susano'o technique?

Tags: naruto

The Uchiha and any Sharingan user who awakens the double Mangekyou Sharingan have the ability to use the Susano'o technique, and each Sharingan user seems to have a unique Susano'o form.
But what exactly is the Susano'o? Is it a deity, a special form of invocation or just a materialized form of chakra? Has this been explained in the manga so far?

Answer (score 4):

[image]
[Susanoo](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Susanoo) is an ability granted to those who awaken the powers of both their Mangekyō Sharingan. **It creates a gigantic, humanoid being that surrounds the user and fights on their behalf. As one of the strongest techniques granted to those that have acquired the Mangekyō Sharingan, it is the user's guardian deity**, but at the same time, it consumes the user's life force and damages their body over time

The answer to your question is : **Susanoo is a materialized form of user's chakra.**

> According to Sasuke Uchiha, if a Sharingan user unlocks two Mangekyō
>   Sharingan powers, one in each eye, known as the "Double Mangekyō"
>   (ダブル万華鏡, Daburu Mangekyō), it gives access the third power, Susanoo.
>   Nevertheless, for a Sharingan user to activate Susanoo, according to
>   Obito Uchiha, is a rarity. **Since it is formed through the
>   materialisation of the user's chakra, its abilities, appearance and
>   colour vary among individuals.** While the user usually remains
>   grounded within Susanoo, it is possible for them to freely move around
>   within its body, as well as levitate inside of it. The user can allow
>   others to enter Susanoo, or leave its body entirely. While Susanoo
>   acts as a defence against external attacks, anything coming out of
>   Susanoo will simply phase through it.

Source : [Naruto wikia : Susanoo](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Susanoo)

Comment: So...it's the user guardian deity or a materialized form of user chakra? The answer state both

Comment: guardian deity is just a reference to susanoo. Since the chakra molds itself in the form of a guardian angel it has been referred as a deity.

Comment: Manifestation of chakra and it has been told that "Susanoo" is an ethereal warrior. So in Naruto wiki, they sometime mentioned it as "Summon" a Susanoo.

Answer (score 1):

From naruto wikia:

> Susanoo is an ability granted to those who awaken the powers of both
>   their Mangekyō Sharingan. It creates a gigantic, humanoid being that
>   surrounds the user and fights on their behalf. As one of the strongest
>   techniques granted to those that have acquired the Mangekyō Sharingan,
>   it is the user's guardian deity, but at the same time, it consumes the
>   user's life force and damages their body over time.[1]